# In python, how can I see where an object that is about to be garbage collected is originating from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection, filehandle

Somewhere in my program, I get a `ResourceWarning` saying that a file handle has been deleted that did not call `close()`. However, I am in a giant project and cannot easily find the file handle.

How can I use the `gc` library to log the name of the file handle's file, or the name of the file in which I create the file handle?

Btw, I am sure the problem has to do with garbage collection, because if I prefix my script with `gc.disable()`, I don't see the warning.

Update: I only see the Warning log when I run from the context of `unittest.main()`.

Comment: The warning should include the file name; how exactly are you receiving the warning?

Comment: The filename its including looks like the filename of where&when the gc is being used. There are no open file descriptors in the file it references

Comment: You aren't getting something like `ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='xxxxxxxx' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>`? That's what I get with `f = open("xxxxxxxx"); del f`.

Comment: Turns out I just did not recognize the filename